# Maven Projects Made With Java FX Unable To Locate The Main Class

Tags: java, javafx

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.mavenproject1.App
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I am trying to compile a maven project made with javafx to a jar file. When I try to run the built jar file, it displays the above error. I have already added the maven plugin

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.packages.to.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I am using NetBeans IDE. The project precisely is an FXML JavaFX maven archetype Gluon project with maven. I suppose it doesn't use the JavaFX that one has manually added since it doesn't allow addition of libraries. It most probably has to do with javafx.

I've tried adding the path to javafx.fxml and javafx controls to the vm options/ arguments but in vain. The issue persisted. I've tried building jars from maven projects that don't use javafx and they function perfectly (by just adding that plugin).

Comment: " When I try to run the built jar file, it displays the above error. I have already added the maven plugin" you cannot really do that with javafx. They have a somewhat special way of starting the application. Have you checked out the javafx plugin? https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin it works nice for creating small jlinked jvms

Answer (score 0):

I achieve running the jar with shade plugin.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>com.mascix.swaggerific.SwaggerApplication</mainClass>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After this plugin, run **mvn package** which will generate the full jar with everything. But this will not be enough for javafx because it requires javafx sdk. so when I run the command(**java -jar target/swaggerific-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**) I got

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I have sdkman installed gluon java version.

> java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules "javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml" -jar target/swaggerific-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

and the env variable is

```bash
echo $PATH_TO_FX
/home/oz-mint/tools/javafx-sdk-21.0.1/lib
```

I highly suggest compile with gluon graalvm and run native binary. That will be easier to use. You can find example code and project [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/blob/main/pom.xml#L272) used for this answer.

[bash jar run example video](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/assets/604405/786f315c-8c68-40a6-8ba2-5dd12fb9c7ed)

Comment: Hey there! I was able to run my own program compiled using the maven jar plugin by specifying the path to javafx but wouldn't it be more convenient to be able to run the jar without having to give the paths to fx? (maybe by somehow adding those arguments to the manifest manually) Or maybe I could create a launcher that runs the command in terminal? Do you know a way?
Really appreciate your reply.

Comment: Hi @ThinkingSpaghetti29 you can use jlink as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830299/175554) or you can use **mvn gluonfx:build gluonfx:nativerun** which will generate the executable file. [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/blob/main/pom.xml#L286) you can find how to configure the maven gluon plugin